# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable - What is wrong with my second For loop?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, request

Why am I getting a typeerror here?

```
import csv

import requests
page = requests.get("URL.com")


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

listitems = {}
for a in soup.select('a.sitemaplink', href=True):
    listitems.update({a.text:a['href']})


for b in listitems.values:
    newpage = requests.get("URL.com"+b)
```

I need to be able to access the links which are now stored as values in listitems

Comment: You want `.values()` not `.values`

Comment: You need to call the function using `values()`  Check my answer below @MikeManieri :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate on the values of the dictionary using `listitems.values()` and not `listitems.values` since you cannot iterate on a builtin function, which is the error you are seeing

```
for b in listitems.values():
    newpage = requests.get("URL.com"+b)
```